# Where is the joel test on jobs.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, joel-test

Is there a reason why the [joel test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) isn't on the jobs.stackoverflow site?   It's pretty handy to have and seems appropriate for that site.

Edit: So this was my fault.   I did a search for jobs and none of the jobs had joel test scores so I though it wasn't implemented.

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean?

Companies that have opted to include the Joel Test are shown with a number in a green circle next to their name that represents the number of "points" they have on the Joel Test.

If you are a company posting a job, the job posting page has check boxes for every part of the Joel Test and you check the ones that apply to your company, along with a check box to opt-out of showing the Joel Test results. There is also a link to the Joel Test blog posting on that same page.

Comment: I actually posted an answer about why companies wouldn't want the test and here it turns out it is on there actually. This is what I get for answering a question without having apparently seen the board anymore than the OP.